# Meteor + Angular 2: How to serve images

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

From what I understood you need to create a /public folder at the root of your Meteor+Angular2 project, and drop images you want to serve here (well in /public/images folder for example).
Thing is when I do that and ask for my image in my Angular2 component... I don't get it

[Here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjYsy.png)

[My network trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRgqV.png)

The strange thing is that it returns a 200 status, but with text/html type and the size is 7.4KB where it should be 35KB...

What am I missing or doing wrong here ?
Thanks for your help

Clmmmm

Comment: The text/html might mean it's an error message of some kind. Your url for the image is something like /images/myimage.png, right?

Comment: yes it is: <img src="/images/myimage.png">

Comment: It should work, can you view the image separately?

Comment: I managed to make it work now.... Thanks for your help. I had those 3 modules missing from my devDependencies section in my package.json : "typings": "^1.3.3",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
"css-loader": "^0.25.0"
They are missing from the angular2-meteor boilerplate
When you do a git clone https://github.com/bsliran/angular2-meteor-base